# Matlab - sum all elements above current

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to implement a vectorised solution in matlab for adding all elements above the current element in a vector. For eg.

I have a vector **a** as follows

```
a =

   1
   2
   3
   4
```

I would like a vector **b** like

```
b =

    1
    3
    6
   10
```

I know this can be done very easily using a loop but I was wondering if there are indexing options which can allow me to do the same in matlab/ octave?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [Cumulative Summation function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) (`cumsum`):

`b = cumsum(a)`